# Best way to check mysql connection in YII2

Tags: php, mysql, yii2

I am writing an console application in YII2. This application must run a long time. In yii.php configured execution time and mysql connection time like this:

```
set_time_limit(0);
ini_set("memory_limit", -1);
ini_set('mysql.connect_timeout', 6000);
ini_set('default_socket_timeout', 6000);
```

My application controller `updater` and an action `hook`. I ran this action via SSH like this:

```
nohup php /path/to/project/yii updater/hook &
```

After 30 min this process was killed. In `nohup.out` file I had detected error like this:

```
Error: SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 2006 MySQL server has gone away
```

How I can fix this error. Please help me!
And how to write a long time running applications (php and mysql, yii2) correct.

Comment: have you tried this ignore_user_abort(1);

Comment: it seems something killed your mysql connection during execution, but just to be sure, try checking out for your cause in the documentation, it even includes fixes for some cases: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/gone-away.html

Answer (score 0):

You must set user abort true ignore_user_abort(1); 
[ignore-user-abort](http://php.net/manual/en/function.ignore-user-abort.php)